# How do I explicitly mention which branch changes to apply while merging two conflicting branches in git?

Tags: git, github, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches in git. Master and feature.

```
O---O (master)
 \ 
  O (feature)
```

I had a text file which contains `Master` when it is at master branch head.
The same file contains `feature` when it is at feature branch head.

I want to rebase the feature branch on to master. Since they both have conflicting changes there will be a rebase conflict (or merge conflict).

I want to know if there is a way to explicitly tell git, I want changes from feature branch in feature branch during the rebase.

This is what I tried:

[image: Image showing setup]

[image: Image showing error]

We can clearly see that the feature branch text is being overwriten by the master branch text.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rebase the `feature` branch onto `master` branch, with the changes on `feature` branch to override `master` branch in case of any merge conflicts, you must pass `--strategy-option` with `theirs` instead of `ours`.

When you are checked out on the `feature` branch, and want to rebase `master` onto `feature`, **git rebase** works by replaying each commit from the `feature` branch on top of the `master` branch. Because of this, when a merge conflict happens, the side reported as **ours** is the `master` branch, and **theirs** is the working branch, ie the `feature` branch.

From the documentation of [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---strategy-optionltstrategy-optiongt) :

> Rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the working branch on top of the upstream branch. Because of this, when a merge conflict happens, the side reported as ours is the so-far rebased series, starting with upstream, and theirs is the working branch. In other words, the sides are swapped.

So try with `git rebase master --strategy-option=theirs` and that would make sure that the `feature` branch changes are considered in case of the merge conflict.